# python: combine sort-key-functions itemgetter and str.lower

Tags: python, function, sorting, key

I want to sort a list of dictionaries by dictionary key, where I don't want to distinguish between upper and lower case characters.

```
dict1 = {'name':'peter','phone':'12355'}
dict2 = {'name':'Paul','phone':'545435'}
dict3 = {'name':'klaus','phone':'55345'}
dict4 = {'name':'Krishna','phone':'12345'}
dict5 = {'name':'Ali','phone':'53453'}
dict6 = {'name':'Hans','phone':'765756'}
list_of_dicts = [dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4,dict5,dict6]

key_field = 'name'
list_of_dicts.sort(key=itemgetter(key_field))
# how to combine key=itemgetter(key_field) and key=str.lower? 
for list_field in list_of_dicts:
    print list_field[key_field]
```

should provide

```
Ali, Hans, klaus, Krishna, Paul, peter
```

and not

```
klaus, peter, Ali, Hans, Krishna, Paul
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the general case, you'll want to write your key-extraction function for sorting purposes; only in special (though important) cases it happens that you can just reuse an existing callable to extract the keys for you, or just conjoin a couple of existing ones (in a "quick and dirty" way using `lambda`, since there's no built-in way to do function composition).

If you often need to perform these two kinds of operations for key extraction (get an item and call a method on that item), I suggest:

```
def combiner(itemkey, methodname, *a, **k):
  def keyextractor(container):
    item = container[itemkey]
    method = getattr(item, methodname)
    return method(*a, **k)
  return keyextractor
```

so `listofdicts.sort(key=combiner('name', 'lower'))` will work in your case.

Note that while excessive generalization has costs, tasteful and moderate generalization (leaving the item key, method name, and method arguments if any, as runtime-determined, in this case) generally has benefits -- one general function, not more complex than a dozen specific and specialized ones (with the extractor, method to call, or both, hardwired in their code), will be easier to maintain (and, of course, much easier to reuse!-).

Answer (score 16):

How about this:

```
list_of_dicts.sort(key=lambda a: a['name'].lower())
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from functools import partial

def nested_funcs(*funcs):
    return partial(reduce, lambda arg, func: func(arg), funcs)


sorted(list_of_dicts, key=nested_funcs(itemgetter('name'), str.strip, str.lower))
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably should go with a lambda for the sake of readability. But as an interesting study into higher order functions, here's the extended version of q-combinator in Python (also known as the queer bird combinator). This allows you to create a new function by composing two functions

```
 def compose(inner_func, *outer_funcs):
     if not outer_funcs:
         return inner_func
     outer_func = compose(*outer_funcs)
     return lambda *args, **kwargs: outer_func(inner_func(*args, **kwargs))

 from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller
 name_lowered = compose(itemgetter('name'), methodcaller('lower'))
 print(name_lowered( {'name': 'Foo'} ))
```

If you reverse the definitions of inner and outer in the `compose` function, you get the more traditional b-combinator (bluebird). I like the q-combinator more because of the similarity to unix pipes.

Answer (score 4):

This solution will use your system locale, and as a bonus, it will sort eventual other characters according to the current locale as well (Will put "ü" after "u" in a german locale etc).

```
from locale import setlocale, strxfrm, LC_ALL
import operator

# call setlocale to init current locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")

def locale_keyfunc(keyfunc):  
  def locale_wrapper(obj):
    return strxfrm(keyfunc(obj))
  return locale_wrapper

list_of_dicts.sort(key=locale_keyfunc(operator.itemgetter("name")))
```

This of course uses that the locale sort is the User interface "natural" sort that you wish to emulate with .lower().

I'm amazed that python's `locale` module is unknown and unused, it for sure is an important component in the application I write (translated to multiple languages, but the locale module is important for even getting *one* module right. Case in point: in swedish 'V' and 'W' sort alike, so you have to collate them. `locale` does all that for you.).
In the `POSIX` locale (not default), this will revert to sorting "a" after "Z".

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, just change keyfunc to:
     
    def keyfunc(dic):
           return strxfrm(dic["name"])

Comment: Francesco: Now it uses a more customizable factory style (although it can be specialized to be quicker, it rarely matters).

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I wish there were two functions in the Python standard library (probably in functools):

```
def compose(*funcs):
    """
    Compose any number of unary functions into a single unary
    function.

    >>> import textwrap
    >>> str.strip(textwrap.dedent(compose.__doc__)) == compose(str.strip, textwrap.dedent)(compose.__doc__)
    True
    """

    compose_two = lambda f1, f2: lambda v: f1(f2(v))
    return reduce(compose_two, funcs)

def method_caller(method_name, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return a function that will call a named method on the
    target object with optional positional and keyword
    arguments.

    >>> lower = method_caller('lower')
    >>> lower('MyString')
    'mystring'
    """
    def call_method(target):
        func = getattr(target, method_name)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return call_method
```

I have implemented these for my own use in [jaraco.util.functools](https://svn.jaraco.com/jaraco/python/jaraco.util/jaraco/util/functools.py).

Either way, now your code is quite clear, self-documented, and robust (IMO).

```
lower = method_caller('lower')
get_name = itemgetter('name')
lowered_name = compose(lower, get_name)

list_of_dicts.sort(key=lowered_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def lower_getter(field):
    def _getter(obj):
        return obj[field].lower()
    return _getter

list_of_dicts.sort(key=lower_getter(key_field))
```

Comment: and as a plus, it will automatically work with both bytestrings and unicode strings.