# How do I sort a list of python Django objects?

Tags: python, django, list, sorting

In Django, I have a model object in a list.

```
[object, object, object]
```

Each object has ".name" which is the title of the thing.

How do I sort alphabetically by this title?

This doesn't work:

```
catlist.sort(key=lambda x.name: x.name.lower())
```

Comment: It would help if you read error messages, the one for your code points **exactly on the dot** in `x.name`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
catlist.sort(key=lambda x: x.name.lower())
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the call to `lower()`, the following could be considered slightly cleaner than using a lambda:

```
import operator
catlist.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('name'))
```

Add that call to `lower()`, and you enter into a world of function-composition pain.  Using [Ants Aasma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107366/ants-aasma)'s `compose()` found in an answer to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394475/python-combine-sort-key-functions-itemgetter-and-str-lower/1394862#1394862), you too can see the light that is functional programming (I'm kidding. All programming paradigms surely have their time and place.):

```
>>> def compose(inner_func, *outer_funcs):
...     if not outer_funcs:
...         return inner_func
...     outer_func = compose(*outer_funcs)
...     return lambda *args, **kwargs: outer_func(inner_func(*args, **kwargs))
...
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self, name):
...     self.name = name
...
>>> L = [A(i) for i in ['aa','a','AA','A']]
>>> name_lowered = compose(operator.attrgetter('name'), 
                           operator.methodcaller('lower'))
>>> print [i.name for i in sorted(L, key=name_lowered)]
['a', 'A', 'aa', 'AA']
```