# pyhon sort lists of dicts by n values and case insensitive

Tags: python

This sorts by two values of the dicts:

```
results = sorted(results, key=itemgetter('category', 'elementName'))
```

How can I make the sort case-insensitive?

Comment: Pass a function that returns the `'elementName'` item converted to lowercase instead of unchanged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: combine sort-key-functions itemgetter and str.lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394475/python-combine-sort-key-functions-itemgetter-and-str-lower)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[str.casefold](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) could be useful here:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

results = [{'category': 'a', 'elementName': "B"},
           {'category': 'a', 'elementName': 'c'},
           {'category': 'a', 'elementName': 'a'}]

results = sorted(
    results,
    key=lambda r: tuple(
        map(str.casefold, itemgetter('category', 'elementName')(r))
    )
)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[{'category': 'a', 'elementName': 'a'}, {'category': 'a', 'elementName': 'B'},
 {'category': 'a', 'elementName': 'c'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work for you

```
results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: (x["category"], x["elementName"].lower()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try making copies where every key is in lower case, you could discard them later.